# Erro "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" ao tentar trazer dados em formato JSON de outra URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Estou tentando trazer dados de uma `URL` que retorna `JSON` para usar na minha página. Aparentemente estou conseguindo trazer os dados, mas por algum motivo recebo o seguinte erro no console do browser:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :".

Por ora, a única coisa que estou fazendo é trazer os dados e jogar no `log` do console por `jquery`. o código que estou usando é o seguinte:

```
function logResults(json){
console.log(json);
}

$.ajax({
url: "https://blockchain.info/pt/ticker",
dataType: "jsonp",
jsonpCallback: "logResults"
});
```

Comment: E ai conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisei fazer algumas alterações para funcionar:

`dataType: "jsonp"` para  `dataType: "json"`;

`jsonpCallback: "logResults"` para  `success: logResults`

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://blockchain.info/pt/ticker",
        dataType: "json",
        success:  logResults,               
});
```

Resumindo o tipo de retorno é `json` e não `jsonp`.

Por não ser `jsonp` o `callback jsonpCallback` não é chamado.

Para obter o retorno é necessário utilizar o `callback success`.

Comment: Vlw pela dica, amigo, mas quando faço as alterações sugeridas tenho outro erro: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://blockchain.info/pt/ticker. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Consegui aqui, amogo, adicionei um "proxy", antes da URL adicionei um "http://cors.io/?u" na frente, então a URL ficou: ["http://cors.io/?uhttps://blockchain.info/pt/ticker"], então os dados vieram. Muchas gracias!

Comment: estou tendo o mesmo problema, se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço